# jquery toggleClass without animation

Tags: jquery

I want `toggleClass` to have the effect of `hide` and `show`, which is an abrupt showing and hiding of an element without any sign of a fade. In other words, I do not want any fade in or fade out animation which seems to come baked with `toggleClass` and `removeClass` and `addClass`. Does anyone know how to use jQuery's `toggleClass` without the fading animation?

Comment: Neither `.toggleClass()`, `.addClass()`, nor `.removeClass()` perform any sort of animation. Are you changing classes that use CSS transitions or animations?

Comment: [Read the documentation for `toggleClass`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) and note that you have to go out of your way to add animation.

Comment: Can you post your code and a fiddle to display the issue?

Comment: Thank you all for the comments. @j08691 you hit the nail on the head. There's an `opacity` set on this element that's creating a fade.